# Should out of date/obsolete questions be closed

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, vote-to-close

[This question about a sky object from 2013](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/703/very-bright-star-in-the-east-at-northern-hemisphere-what-is-it) is of not much value anymore, even if we assume an event that repeats yearly.

(It's not a good question either: no location, no picture or sketch)

Do we close questions like this because they are obsolete?

With what reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general they should be left. The example you gave is a poor question, and could be closed as "unclear", but a good answer can be given to a such a question along the lines of "That was Jupiter, and here is how you can identify sky objects...", or "No, the bright star in south at midnight was not Venus, and here is why..."

Answers like these can improve the "sky literacy" of people who browse this site.